# Find the time period ($T$) for an electric field wave: $E=E_0\sin{m t}\sin{2mt}$

Tags: functions, wave-equation, electromagnetism

> Find the time period ($T$) for an electric field wave: $E=E_0\sin{m t}\sin{2mt}$

I thought $T$ is such that, $E(T+t) = E(t)$. As period of given sinusoidal function $E$ is 2$\pi$,
$$ \Rightarrow 2\pi = mT \Rightarrow T = 2\pi/m$$

But, I was wrong. How to do it correctly?

---

The correct answer is:

> $6π/m$

---

**Edit:** I plotted the graph after suggestion by PM 2Ring on [fooplot](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiJzaW4oeClzaW4oMngpIiwiY29sb3IiOiIjMDAwMDAwIn0seyJ0eXBlIjoxMDAwLCJzaXplIjpbNjQ4LDM5OF19XQ--) and got the period as $2\pi$ (in graph, $m =1$).

Comment: Hint: what's $\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B)$ ?

Comment: @PM2Ring: then I get two wave-functions. Should I have to take $LCM$ of the two time periods?

Comment: I think you should graph the function and see for yourself what its period is. A picture is more powerful than words (or equations). ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring: I agree (with your point) as well as disagree (as I can't do that in exam). Btw, I've tried plotting it on [fooplot](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiJzaW4oeClzaW4oMngpIiwiY29sb3IiOiIjMDAwMDAwIn0seyJ0eXBlIjoxMDAwLCJzaXplIjpbNjQ4LDM5OF19XQ--). I placed $m=1$ and then I get period = $2π$. Why it is so?

Comment: Fundamental period is $2\pi/m$ although $6\pi/m$ is also a period

Comment: @jeea: this question is a piece of [this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5Sgz.jpg), where $f = 1/T$ and we've to find maximum $f$ (i.e., resonant / fundamental frequency)

Answer (score 1):

You have correctly stated the condition for periodicity is $E(t+T)=E(t)$ but then proceed to ignore that, in particular, the form of E.

Using this and the hint given by PM2Ring, I’m sure you can work it out.

Comment: @Rahul Verma this post is enough to find the solution.

Comment: @many sorry, but I'm still in chaos. I understood that $E=\frac{E_0}{2}(\cos(mt)-\cos(3mt))$. Then, $T_1 = 2\pi/m, T_2 = 2\pi/3m$. So, overall time period would be $2\pi/m$. Where i'm wrong?

Comment: @RahulVerma Fundamental period is $2\pi/m$ although $6\pi/m$ is also a period

Comment: @jeea: this question is a piece of [this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5Sgz.jpg), where $f = 1/T$ and we've to find maximum $f$ (i.e., resonant / fundamental frequency)

Comment: In that case find the threshold frequency and check if both the cos waves are above that frequency. I’m guessing only the 3mt one is above the threshold.

Answer (score 0):

The period is indeed $2\pi/m$. What may appear confusing is that the field is not a harmonic function of time, but rather a sum of two harmonic functions, as it has been noted in the comments:
$$E(t) = E_0\sin mt \sin 2mt = \frac{E_0}{2}\left[\cos m t - \cos 3 m t\right].$$
The period of $\cos m t$ is $T_1=2\pi/m$, whereas the period of $\cos 3 m t$ is $T_2=2\pi/(3m)$, i.e. three times shorter. Since the two periods are commensurate (i.e. their ratio is an integer, $T_1/T_2=3$), the whole wave is still periodic and repeats itself after $T=T_1 = 2\pi/m$! So this is the correct answer, although the person who posed the question probably expected the above cited reasoning about the two periodic waves.

**Note for moderators**
This may appear as a complete answer to a homework question. Note however that this homework question is badly formulated and I needed to provide all the details in order to clarify it.